# $X=U_1\cup\dots\cup\ U_n\implies X=K_1\cup\dots\cup K_n$ with $U_i$ open, $K_i$ closed

Tags: functional-analysis

I have some questions to the proof of the following exercise;

$1)$ How can one justify in the $2$nd line of the proof that $\overline{V_{i,x}}\subseteq U_i$,

$2)$ What is wrong with $\bigcup\limits_{x\in U_i}V_{i,x}$, why can we not take $V_i:=\bigcup\limits_{x\in U_i}V_{i,x}$ instead of $V_i:=\bigcup\limits_{x\in L_i}V_{i,x}$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re 1) For $x \in U_i$ there's some $\epsilon > 0$ such that the open ball $N(x, \epsilon) \subseteq U_i$, so letting $V_i = N(x, \epsilon /2)$, we get $\overline{V_i} \subseteq \{y \mid \mathsf{d}(x,y) \le \epsilon /2\} \subseteq N(x, \epsilon) \subseteq U_i$.

Re 2) $L_i$ is finite, but $U_i$ in general is not. Each $V_{i,x} \subseteq \overline{V_{i,x}} \subseteq U_i$, so the closure of a finite union of them is the union of their closures and also contained in $U_i$, but that need not be the case for the closure of the union of all $V_{i,x}$ for $x \in U_i$ – that union equals $U_i$!.

Comment: 1) but you do the same,  I mean who guarantees that the boundary of $N(x, \epsilon/2)$ has no thickness ?

Comment: But $\overline{ N(x, \epsilon /2)} \subseteq \{y \mid distance(x,y) \le  \epsilon /2\} \subseteq N(x, \epsilon)$

Comment: (I added the previous comment to the answer - it was worth saying.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

1) Every metrizable space is normal.

2) Why would you have $\overline{\bigcup_{x\in U_i}V_{i,x}}\subseteq U_i$ ?

Take for exemple, $$I_n=\left]-1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right[$$ You have that $I_n\subset]-1,1[$ for all $n$ but $$\overline{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}I_n}=[-1,1]\not\subset ]-1,1[.$$